# How to connect to Cisco AnyConnect VPN via GUI in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vpn, gui, cisco

I've installed the Cisco AnyConnect on Ubuntu 18.04 via:

```
sudo apt-get install openconnect
```

and I've connect well via:

```
sudo openconnect cz.cisadd2.com
```

But how can I add my Cisco AnyConnect VPN to the GUI part of Network -> VPN prompt of Ubuntu? In other words, how can I connect Cisco AnyConnect via GUI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install package "network-manager-openconnect-gnome", such as by CLI:

```
$ sudo apt install network-manager-openconnect-gnome
```